# Veins Attempted to read past end of byte buffer

Tags: runtime-error, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using instant veins with simulte, I created my own scenario that includes vehicles and pedestrians.
When I tried to run my simulation, I got this error:
Attempted to read past end of byte buffer -- in module ( veins::VeinsInetManager)
I don't think that is related to a sumo and veins versions' compatibility because sumo is preinstalled in the virtual machine instant veins, but I tried export SUMO_HOME ="$PWD/sumo" and it doesn't work.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. After adding following code in configuration file (sumo.cfg), it is fixed.

```
<report>
    <xml-validation value="never"/>
</report>
```